# Transform several disjunctions to implications

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to transform a statement which only consists of disjunctions to a statement which only consists of implications.

My statement: j => (a | b | c | d)
Goal: new statement with only implications

**My idea:**
1. step: j => e | f where e = a | b and f = c | d
2. step: j => (not e => f)
3. step: j => ((not (not a => b)) => (not c => d))

I need for a homework puzzle. But apparently, my solution is wrong.

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: What is the suggested solution ? I think : $\lnot a \to (\lnot b \to (\lnot c \to d))$

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to :

> $j \to (a \lor b \lor c \lor d)$,

applying the equivalence : $(p \lor q) \equiv (\lnot p \to q)$ from right to left,  leads to :

> $j \to [\lnot a \to ( \lnot b \to (\lnot c \to d))]$.

Using [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)) we have that : $\lnot a \to ( \lnot b \to (\lnot c \to d))$ is equivalent to : $(\lnot a \land \lnot b) \to (\lnot c \to d)$.

Now the last step : $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \equiv \lnot (\lnot p \to q)$.

Using it, what we finally get is :

> > $j \to (a \lor b \lor c \lor d) \equiv j \to [\lnot a \to ( \lnot b \to (\lnot c \to d))] \equiv j \to [\lnot (\lnot a \to b) \to (\lnot c \to d)]$.